# Importing a simple elevation raster to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, elevation, arcgis-online-webmap, web-scene

I have a very simple elevation raster that I want to bring in to AGOL for use in a web map or web scene. I need to preserve the elevation data. I have tried to bring it in as a tile service but I lose all the elevation data. I feel like this should be a fairly simple task but I've spent hours trying to figure it out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello @Sam, its ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro? Also, how are you expecting your output to be, as the elevation can be viewed in a web scene?

Comment: @YogeshChavan   I have the elevation raster in ArcGIS Pro, and yes, I am hoping for an output that can be viewed in a web scene or web map

Answer (score 1):

I used a **DEM** to use in ArcGIS Online as a web scene.

Kindly follow the below workflow to host a scene in ArcGIS Online and use it in an application.

1. In ArcGIS Pro add a new global scene
2. Add the elevation raster in the 3D layers list
3. Apply any symbology
4. Navigate to the share tab and select the web scene
5. Once the scene is shared, launch ArcGIS Online(AGOL)
6. Navigate to the contents tab and open the web scene in AGOL Scene Viewer
   [image]

[image]

[image]